# Standard cancel button in lightning:recordform not closing the quick action dialogue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-record-form

I am creating a lightning component which shows opportunity in edit mode using lightning:recordform tag(summer 18 salesforce release). Now when I am clicking on cancel button it should close the quick action dialogue but it is displaying the same record in view mode on same quick action dialogue.

[image: Edit form using lightning:recordform]

[image: After clicking cancel button on screen]

code sample :

```
<lightning:recordForm 
     recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
     objectApiName="Opportunity" 
     layoutType="Full" 
     columns="2"
     mode="edit"
     onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add "oncancel" as an attribute:

```
<lightning:recordForm 
 recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
 objectApiName="Opportunity" 
 layoutType="Full" 
 columns="2"
 mode="edit"
 onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
 oncancel="{!c.handleCancel}"/>
```

For some reason it is not in their documentation which can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/specification) but it works for me!

Hopefully this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `lightning:recordEditForm` specifically and manually handle the cancel button with a `lightning:button`.

[Per the current spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/specification), there isn't a way to override the default actions within `lightning:recordForm`.

Edit: This is theoretical, I don't know if this will work but it could

Given the following setup:

```
<aura:attribute name="formMode" type="String" default="edit"/>

<lightning:recordForm 
     recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
     objectApiName="Opportunity" 
     layoutType="Full" 
     columns="2"
     mode="{! v.formMode }"
     onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>

<aura:handler name="change" value="{! v.formMode }" action="{! c.handleFormModeChange }"/>
```

You might be able to listen to a mode change and fire the close event manually. I bet you're going to get a bit of lag though since it takes a millisecond for the change handler to process.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Add on oncancel function to the lightning:recordForm

```
<lightning:recordForm 
     recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
     objectApiName="Opportunity" 
     layoutType="Full" 
     columns="2"
     mode="{! v.formMode }"
     onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
     oncancle="{!c.handleCancel}"
/>
```

Then perform this action in the controller

```
handleCancel : function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    window.history.back();
    return false;
}
```